# How to set a different command to each button, when buttons are created without names

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I set it so that all 10 buttons each have a different command using this code:

line1 = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p']

```
for n in range(10):
        tkinter.Button(keyboard, text = line1[n], command = line1[n]).grid(column = n + 1, row = 0, padx = 1, pady = 1)
```

Current Code:

```
line1 = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p']

functions = [lambda: q(), lambda: w(), lambda: e(), lambda: r(), lambda: t(), lambda: y(), lambda: u(), lambda: i(), lambda: o(), lambda: p()]
    buttons = []
    def q():
        buttons[0].destroy()
    def selectCallback(n):
        global functions
        global buttons
        if n > 1:
            functions[2](n)
        else:
            functions[n]()
    for n in range(10):
        buttons.append(tkinter.Button(keyboard, text = line1[n], command = lambda n = n: selectCallback(n)))
        buttons[n].grid(column = n + 1, row = 0, padx = 1, pady = 1)
```

When this is run it causes the error.

Comment: Depends on what kind of commands you want to give them,

Comment: You ask about a "different command", but you're not referencing a command, you're referencing an element in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback for callbacks!

Probably not the most elegant solution but you can have one main function which decides which function to use based on the argument given by the button.

You will need to decide what each value of `n` will call.

**EDIT**: Changed code answer comment

```
import Tkinter

keyboard = Tkinter.Tk()
line1 = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p']
buttons = []
def func0():

    print("This could be 0's function")
    buttons[0].destroy()

def func1():

    print("This could be 1's function")
    buttons[1].destroy()

def funcX(n):


    print("You get the idea...")
    buttons[n].destroy()

functions = [lambda: func0(), lambda: func1(), lambda n: funcX(n)]

def selectCallback(n):

    global functions
    global buttons
    # If `functions` is filled out for all elements you can neglect this 
    # if/else and simply call `functions[n]()`
    if n > 1:
        functions[2](n)
    else:
        functions[n]()

for n in range(10):
        buttons.append(Tkinter.Button(keyboard, text = line1[n], command = lambda n = n: selectCallback(n)))
        buttons[n].grid(column = n + 1, row = 0, padx = 1, pady = 1)

keyboard.mainloop()
```

**Important points**:

-Must keep a reference to the buttons to be able to delete them (`buttons`)

-Must call `.grid()` on a *separate line* so it does not return `None` for what should be the `Button`.

-If all you want to do is delete the buttons, this does not require a different function for each. This example is meant to illustrate how you could have 10 different functions as callbacks.

-Additionally, my example is simplified: for buttons [2:9] I only call one function and pass an index so that I don't have to write out 10 functions. If you want to do a different function that performs a different operation for each button, fill out the `functions` list properly and remove the `if/else` construct within `selectCallback(n)`, and access each function directly by its index.

Comment: How could I make it so that the command removes the button that has been pressed?

Comment: Do you know what I need to add to answer the question above

Comment: Check out the new code/explanation.

Comment: When I press one of the buttons, it comes up with an error saying that the global name 'functions' is not defined in the line that says:

Comment: else: functions[n]() @maccartm

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly (I've just removed the `type` call surrounding the first `functions[2](n)` as it was something I used for testing & useless. If you did there should be no problem, if not make sure functions is defined before `selectCallback` and that you include the `global functions` line

Comment: Tried everything you've just said and it's still giving me the error

Comment: Can you post your code either in your question or in a chat?

Comment: Just edited the question to contain the code I currently have

Comment: [I've moved this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82880/set-different-command-to-each-button) to limit the amount of comments and edits that we have to make.

Comment: Still giving me the error, but I'm going to try and figure it out myself, thank you so much for all the help you have given me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the chatroom, it shows an alternative way of deleting the buttons if that's all you plan on doing. Best of luck